# Python-2.x: list directory without os.listdir()

Tags: python, listdir

With `os.listdir(some_dir)`, we can get all the files from `some_dir`, but sometimes, there would be 20M files(no sub-dirs) under `some_dir`, these would be a long time to return 20M strings from `os.listdir()`.

(We don't think it's a wise option to put 20M files under a single directory, but it's really there and out of my control...)

Is it any other generator-like method to do the list operation like this: once find a file, `yield` it, we fetch it and then the next file.

I have tried `os.walk()`, it's really a generator-style tool, but it also call `os.listdir()` to do the list operation, and it can not handle unicode file names well (UTF-8 names along with GBK names).

Comment: glob.iglob is an iterator...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have python 3.5+ you can use os.scandir() see documentation for [scandir](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.scandir)

Comment: And if you're on pre-3.5 Python, you can get the [`scandir` package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scandir) for earlier versions of Python (it's the code on which 3.5's `os.scandir` was based).

Comment: @ShadowRanger, very helpful comment. thumbs up!